# Can a math intensive application cause a crash?

Tags: crash

I have been messing with hash functions and functions to generate primes etc.

I had 3 lock-ups in a short period. This was odd since my macbook rarely locks-up and usually only when I run out of memory - which does not happen often.

But in this case, I had three in a row and none since (but I also am not generating as much load as before).

Comment: I need to provide some feedback on this since it is not happening now - but that was a few OSs ago.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the CPU overheats and shutdowns itself for safety?

Comment: It certainly slows down, but eventually it has to be hard-reset.